# long runner to regularly update Django DB with web harvested data -?

Tags: python, django, database, sqlite, background-task

My Django project has a user facing site, which infrequently inserts new objects into the user-DB-table (later there will be hundreds, perhaps thousands).

Additionally, a few times per day, I need to query an external webservice, for all my objects - but slowly, so not to violate their "1 request per 10 seconds" rule. So this 2nd task is a long runner, I cannot route it through an urls.py request.

Thus, besides the (uWSGI) server process ... I will have a 2nd process running in the background; it needs to work with the same database (using the default sqlite3).

- can I run into concurrency issues when accessing the same DB? (How) can Django protect me from that? (If not) How to solve?
- importing my models.py - is that all I need to do to access the django DB?
- any other hints that might help me?

Thanks a million!
Stackoverflow rocks!

:-)

Comment: You shouldn't really be using sqlite for anything other than a toy site.

Comment: I know. And I do know how to replace it with postgresql - have done that for another project already. There however, I went back to sqlite3 in the end, because it turned out to be much faster than postgresql; and in that project timing was the most important aspect. Anyways, thanks for that reminder!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django [provides facilities](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/) for writing command line applications as well. This way you have access to all the same things you would from the web process, including the models.

The concurrency is handled by your database, not django, so you don't have to worry about that. The only thing you might want to use are [transactions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/transactions/#controlling-transactions-explicitly) if you have to write multiple pieces of data at the same time and they cannot be out of sync.

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            while True:
                self._fetch_data()
                time.sleep(10)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass

    def _fetch_data(self):
        data = ... # fetch data here
        MyModel.objects.create(foo=data.foo, bar=data.bar) # insert into db
```

Assuming the above class is inside `management/commands/mycommand.py` folder in one of your apps, execute it by using `manage.py`:

```
python manage.py mycommand
```

Comment: Note that with sqlite3, I have had django complain when running concurrent commands; as Daniel Roseman points out in his comment to your question, you really should look at swapping out sqlite for MySQL/Postgresql/etc. Specifically, it threw exceptions so there was not data corruption but that's still a problem to have to detect/retry.

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I need. "custom django-admin commands" == perfect. Will do that.

Comment: Much appreciated! @Anonymous - you can call yourself my "Django hero of the day!" :-) Grrrrreat!

Comment: @Foon - good hint (in my first version and perhaps even later, with postgresql) ... I will then catch those exceptions, and simply move on. Then that field will just get updated one iteration later, and that's fine...

Comment: @AltSheets Glad I could help. If this completely answered your question, please accept the answer.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Thx again. Anonymous - "we are legion" ;-)